# Insert column in existing table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm wondering if there is a way for a user on a site to insert columns in a table.

My situation is: the admin would like to define a table structure each year. Then the admin would like users to insert data into that table.

E.g. on the site it could look like this:
[image: First table]
At a later stage, the admin would like to add an additional column to the table, but to keep the data intact. The table would now look like this:

[image: Additional table]

How can you accommodate this feature? I was thinking of creating a model with a lot of hidden fields that the admin later could "unhide" and name, but I'm not sure this is best practice :).

Any ideas that could solve this would be greatly appreciated! (I'm coding in ruby on rails but I don't think the language is especially relevant in this case)

OXp1845

Comment: See the documentation on the ALTER TABLE command : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Not sure if this will work. The user will add additional columns while being on the website

Comment: From your question it is not totally clear if it is the admin or the user adding the columns? First you ask if it possible for the user to add the column - later you say it is the admin who will do it. The column can be added leaving the remaining content unchanged - depending on the design of your site the pages will then need to display the additional columns and allow user to enter data.

Comment: Not sure why I received a down-vote for this question. Seems a bit harsh.

Comment: Not me - I wondered why too - even if a little unclear to me it seemed a very reasonable question to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend inserting columns but rather use a vertical attributes table. E.g.

```
admin_tables       
| id | year or any other descriptor you want |
  1    2015
  2    2016 

admin_table_columns
| id | admin_table_id | named_column |
  1         1             name
  2         1             description
  3         1             info1
  4         1             info2 
  5         2             name 
  6         2             description
  7         2             info1
  8         2             info2 
  9         2             info3

user_inputs 
| id | user_id| admin_table_column_id | data |
  1      1              1               input for name
  2      1              2               input for description
  3      1              4               input for info2 
     .....
```

This will allow the admin to add as many attributes as they want to a "table" with out altering the existing data or inserting new columns on the fly and models could be defined as:

```
class AdminTable < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :admin_table_columns
   has_many :user_inputs, through: : :admin_table_columns
end 

class AdminTableColumn < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :admin_table
   has_many :user_inputs
end

class UserInput < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :admin_table_column
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Obviously this is a simplified example but I think it should get you on the right track.

Comment: I think this is the right way to go about it. Thank you for your detailed description